Bitmatrix read as vertical is wrong | Javascript
I want to make a website to upload images, resize them to 32x128, convert them to hex bitmatrix with an Filter like dithering or Threshold. For testing I use image2cpp by javl. Reading my bitmatrix as horizontal works and it shows the correct horizontal image:
Working image:

Working code:
//Working Code
//Get Image from Canvas

    matrix = Array.from({ length: height }, (_, i) =>
      Array.from({ length: width }, (_, j) =>
        ctx.getImageData(j, i, 1, 1).data[0] > 0 ? 1 : 0
      )
    );
   
//Convert binary to hex
    return matrix
      .reduce((acc, row) => {
        acc += row.reduce((acc, value) => {
          acc += value > 0 ? "1" : "0";
          return acc;
        }, "");
        return acc;
      }, "")
      .match(/.{1,8}/g)
      .map((byte) => "0x" + parseInt(byte, 2).toString(16));
  

Now i want to read my bitmatrix as vertical.
For that I tried to transpose the matrix and convert it to hex.
But my wrong  looks rotated and split up.
It should be the same as above.
Not working image:

Not working code:
//read as vertical
//not working
    matrix = Array.from({ length: height }, (_, i) =>
      Array.from({ length: width }, (_, j) =>
        ctx.getImageData(j, i, 1, 1).data[0] > 0 ? 1 : 0
      )
    );

//new code
    matrix[0].map((_, colIndex) => matrix.map(row => row[colIndex]));

//same conversion as above
    return matrix
          .reduce((acc, row) => {
           ....



See the code snippet below for a working replacement for your matrix rotate. You were just missing the need to assign the results of your map() calls into a new variable.
Also, I added a .padStart(2,"0") to the end of your bin to hex code, since  image2cpp does not seem to work correctly if you don't pad out to 2 characters.


let ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext( "2d" )
ctx.canvas.width = 32
ctx.canvas.height = 128

// Draw a shape on the canvas
ctx.strokeStyle = "white"
ctx.beginPath( )
ctx.rect( 0, 0, 28, 124 )
ctx.arc( 10, 16, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI )
ctx.stroke( )

let str = ""
for( let next of rotateBinaryToHex() ) {
  str += next
}
console.log( "Paste this into image2cpp and set size to 128 x 32 px")
console.log(str)


function rotateBinaryToHex( ) {
  let width = ctx.canvas.width;
  let height = ctx.canvas.height;
  let matrix = []

  //Get Image from Canvas
  matrix = Array.from({ length: height }, (_, i) =>
    Array.from({ length: width }, (_, j) => ctx.getImageData(j, i, 1, 1).data[0] > 0 ? 1 : 0 )
  );


  //NOTE New "new code" to rotate the matrix 90 degrees
  let rotatedMatrix = matrix[0].map((_, colIndex) => matrix.map(row => row[colIndex]));


  //Convert binary to hex
  // return matrix
  return rotatedMatrix
  .reduce((acc, row) => {
    acc += row.reduce((acc, value) => {
      acc += value > 0 ? "1" : "0";
      return acc;
    }, "");
    return acc;
  }, "")
  .match(/.{1,8}/g)
  // NOTE image2cpp does not seem to display data correctly if you don't pad out to 2 characters
  .map((byte) => "0x" + parseInt(byte, 2).toString(16).padStart(2,"0"));
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

canvas {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px black;
}
<canvas></canvas>



